# Client PC communication with a Host PC over LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

**Short Verstion:** I have a task that I need to make an application get a computer's camera screenshots, and send to another computer running a Windows Service, in the same local network (but not connected to the internet), along with some other information.

**Long Explanation:** We have an application that runs in the background while the user takes a survey, and we get the user's information such as ID and we save his answers along with other information (only pictures at the moment).
We convert these pictures to data and send them to a WebService, which then saves in a server.
Now we're implementing an "offline" version of this functionality, and we're supposed to save the user's data to a specific computer in the local area network, running another application that saves these data to later upload them to the server when it's online.

**Question** What do I need on both PCs for this communication to work?
Is it possible to access the Windows Service in the Host PC if it doesn't have IIS installed? (It'll be a client machine so it probably won't have it).

I've been trying to google to understand what should I search/understand but I couldn't find anything that wasn't about WCF and IIS / Online services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need some form of communication between the 2. It could be TCP/IP sockets or WCF or classic webservices... but if it is webservices then you DO need it hosted in IIS just like WCF. But WCF allows you to not only host it in IIS but it can be self hosting in your application or you can also use the Windows Activation Services (WAS) too. TCP/IP sockets can also be a solution here. I would lean towards TCP/IP Sockets as the problem you describe is more suited for this than a full bloated service.

Comment: For a simple service, he could use a [self hosted Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api). Simpler than sockets, but not nearly as complex as full blown WCF.

Comment: I think WebAPI personally is not quite suited for this (not that It wont work, just not so much for the context) purely because the WebAPI is really for cross platform client API stuff... i.e AJAX/JSON consumption (kind of like a very lightweight WCF but only a small handful of data types/format types). Besides its a little more overhead than raw TCP/IP communication and you have more raw flexibility in what you want to communicate back and forth. But that's just me.